# SVG parameters in image hash

Tags: svg

I'm working with an SVG file that requires the "preserveAspectRatio='true'" on the root  element. The SVG is displayed using a standard  tag. Currently I'm re-adding the attribute each time I update the SVG file in Illustrator. Is there an easier way to apply this attribute via CSS (or otherwise) so that I don't have to continually re-add the attribute?

`<img src="image.svg#preserveAspectRatio=none" />` is the idealistically easy type of implementation I'm hoping for, but my fingers aren't crossed too tight.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax according to the [svg spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG) is:

```
<img src="image.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))" />
```